# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm new to rails 4 i wanted to add multiple image in my app.i tried fix given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460209/error-with-multiple-image-upload).i ended up with new error.

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'pictures.product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT pictures.* FROM pictures WHERE pictures.product_id = 9
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
t.string   "name",               limit: 255
t.integer  "price",              limit: 4
t.text     "description",        limit: 65535
t.text     "reason",             limit: 65535
t.integer  "user_id",            limit: 4
t.string   "image_file_name",    limit: 255
t.string   "image_content_type", limit: 255
t.integer  "image_file_size",    limit: 4
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "status",             limit: 255
t.integer  "category_id",        limit: 4
end
```

can somebody help me with this

Comment: Do you have `product_id` in `pictures` table?

Comment: Can you paste the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

As per your schema you dont have product_id column in products table.

If you want product_id column than you must need yo use ALTER TABLE query and add product_id in products
 table like

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD COLUMN product_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_id);
```

Comment: How can I do that through rails or migrations?